# Do I have the right understanding of frames and bounds in UIKit?

Tags: iphone, uikit, uiview

Let me try to explain it. Please tell me if I am wrong. I am just 70% sure about it.

Like I understand it, an UIView has a frame and an bounds rectangle.
The job of the frame rectangle is to set the position of the UIView relative to it's superview. More precisely: Relative to the coordinate system of the superview. The job of the bounds rectangle is to set the drawing area of the UIView, relative to it's own coordinate system.

Briefly:

- frame rectangle is for positioning the UIView relative to its superview
- bounds rectangle is to set the drawing area of the UIView

Are there any mistakes or important things I missed?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Check out Apple's guide on [View Geometry](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html).  They have pretty good examples on what happens when you change bounds and frame values.

Comment: Thanks! Very good one. Seems like a lot of that mac documentation stuff applies also to the iPhone. Pretty scary though, how much stuff is there to read ;)

Comment: Thanks for the link @calebt. Unfortunately I now have to read it.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! The rule around here is to include the answer, not just link to it.

Comment: Can't believe this answer got about 40 upvotes. Link in the answer is not for UIKit. Correct link is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW6

Answer (score 9):

A view's Frame: the position and size of a rectangle inside the superview where the view will fill.

A view's Bound: the position and size of a rectangle inside the view itself.

Comment: so simple says: View Frame is like x,y,width,height and bounds is like 0,0,width,height am I right?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you are right.

When you need to use the view, then you use the frame; the bounds are used to actually implement the view. As an example, you need to use the bounds to draw a view or to handle touch events. Instead, you use the frame when creating a view or positioning a view in its superview etc.

Answer (score 4):

You are right.

You can use the two interchangably though it's just the frame is easier when using a view and bounds is easier when working inside a view (e.g. in the event handling or drawing code)

Note also that frame is undefined if there is a transform operating on the view.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html

For iOS. Origin coordinate is in different location from Mac OS (upper left, not lower left)