# How to remove the last border of the last cell in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

In my app, I use a `UITableView` 
My problem is that I want to remove the last border of the last cell in `UITableView`.

Please check the following image:

[image]

Comment: Change separatorInset as in this answer stackoverflow.com/a/8561820/1418457

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Updated on 9/14/15. My original answer become obsolete, but it is still a universal solution for all iOS versions:

You can hide `tableView`'s standard separator line, and add your custom line at the top of each cell. The easiest way to add custom separator is to add simple `UIView` of 1px height:

```
UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width, 1)];
separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
```

To date, I subscribe to [another way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5377569/1357250) for hiding extra separators below cells (works for iOS 6.1+):

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: The CGRectZero method did not work for me. However the other answer below which sets the frame to CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 1) did work.

Comment: Genius answer! saved my day.

Comment: Ecuador's comment is right. Answer is not working on iOS 12 and should not be marked as correct as it just removes the separators from empty cells.

Answer (score 141):

The best solution is add a footer view. The following code hide the last cell's line perfectly:

**Objective-C**

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 1)];
```

**Swift 4.0**

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 1))
```

Comment: Works only when you have one section

Comment: @GoodSp33d I have multiple sections and it works by doing it this way
`if(indexPath.row == [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1)
    {
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 1)];
    }`

In the `CellForRowAtIndexPath` datasource

Comment: My bad commented early. Adding only that line, sets the default height to 44 px I guess, so along with that line of code i ahd to pass `1.0f` as footer height in `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section` delegate. Now it works like a charm. Upvoted

Comment: It is incredible that nowadays this hack is still needed...

Comment: @javi_swift 2022

Answer (score 43):

In iOS 7 there is an easier solution. Supposing cell is your last cell:

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, cell.bounds.size.width, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This hides my cells whole contents. Label becomes invisible.

Comment: doesn't work, it just shifts the label to the right.

Comment: Works perfectly for me on iOS 7 with a non-scrolling table with a fixed number of cells, when I apply this to the bottom cell.

Comment: Cannot be used with "standard" cells as the inset determines where the label is positioned. Can be used with customer cells.

Comment: this removes all the separators

Answer (score 13):

This works for me in iOS 7 and 8:

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds));
```

NOTE: be careful about using `tableView.bounds` as it sometimes reports the wrong value depending on when you call it. See [Reporting incorrect bounds in landscape Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194504/reporting-incorrect-bounds-in-landscape-mode)

Comment: Works perfect in iOS8 too. Thanks

Comment: I used this to avoid strange behavior on 5.5 inch screen: `cell!.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.tableView.bounds)-self.view.layoutMargins.left)`

Comment: When the orientation is first in portrait, then in landscape, it appears the line

Answer (score 12):

Add this line of code in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0.001))
```

This make sure the last separator will be replaced and replaced (invisible) footer view will not occupy any extra height. Since the footer view's width will be managed by `UITableView`, so you can set it to 0.

Comment: The only solution that worked for me, the `.zero` left one separator at the bottom of the table.

Comment: @Ido hello, just to let you know that I I rolled back your edit version because I don't think the `CGRect` extension you added is a great practice. If you don't like those cumbersome `0` in the sample code, you can write something like this: `var frame = CGRect.zero \n frame.size.height = 0.001`

Comment: May I ask why isn't it a good practice? It's let you use the same way you can use with `.zero`, but use actual zero (0.001) which do what you need.

Comment: Because it's not flexible enough (what if one day you want a frame with 0.001 width?), and the property name `CGRect.myZero` doesn't provide much of sense of what it can do.

Comment: You can call it `almostZero` if thats what making it not flexible. You can add some comment above the `static let ...` to describe it (with 3 / so you'll be able to see it via the xCode's autocomplete interface).

Answer (score 7):

**Extension based solution for Swift 4, tested on iOS 12**

I noticed that setting a empty view of `height = 1` also removes the separator of the last visible cell however setting `height = 0` just removes the separator of the empty cells

```
extension UITableView {
    func removeSeparatorsOfEmptyCells() {
        tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    }

    func removeSeparatorsOfEmptyCellsAndLastCell() {
        tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Turns out that any positive, non-zero height will do. e.g. 0.1 pts high.

Answer (score 3):

My shorter version:

```
self.tblView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift simply:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Comment: Are you using Swift 3?

Comment: This worked for me. Note I was using a subclass of a `UITableViewController`

Comment: iOS 13.4.1 not work but   ``` tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude, height: .leastNonzeroMagnitude)) ```

Answer (score 3):

This works great for me:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = cell as? yourCell else {
            return
    }
    // Here we're checking if your cell is the last one
    if indexPath.row == numberOfCells.count - 1 {
        cell.separatorInset.left = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    }
}
```

What we're doing here is setting the size of the left inset to be a big enough value so that the separator line won't be visible anymore. So when we increase the size value of our inset it will get closer and closer to the right of our screen since left inset goes towards the right direction.

Comment: Okay, I tried it in the current (Xcode 15RC, iOS 17) environment, and it works. Here's my interpretation of what you described: There is "always" a separator, that I by default height of 1, that provides space between cells so they aren't adjacent. This is even if the inset height is zero. Unless you make an insert that is basically invalid, and that cause the separator to disappear (or have an actual height of zero). [And this handling of the insert doesn't appear to be documented...)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the remedy I currently use. it might not be the best approach, but it works.

Remove SeparatorColor and setSeparatorStyle to make custom separator

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ...

    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    [self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

Add custom separator to each cell with tableview background

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ...

    UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.size.height-1, 320, 1)];
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = self.tableView.backgroundColor;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This won't work with cells with custom height - at the point where you're fetching the cell's height, the cell hasn't been completely laid out. Also, you shouldn't be using hard coded values like 320 - how does this look on an iPhone 6?

Answer (score 1):

```
_tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 7 and above

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        BOOL bIsLastRow = NO;

        //Add logic to check last row for your data source
        NSDictionary *dict = [_arrDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        if([_arrDataSource lastObject] == dict)
        {
           bIsLastRow = YES;
        }

        //Set last row separate inset left value large, so it will go outside of view
        if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) 
        {
            [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, bIsLastRow ? 1000 :0, 0, 0)];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Below code helps me to remove the separator from last row in a UITableView.

### Swift 3.0

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) {
        cell.separatorInset.right = cell.bounds.size.width
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2**

To get a separator that goes from left to right in your last cell, add this in your `UITableViewDataSource's` `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` implementation:

```
if tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1 == indexPath.row {
        cell.separatorInset = .zero
}
```

If you don't want a separator for one particular cell, consider drawing your own separator and set `tableView.separatorStyle = .none`.

Answer (score 1):

**Xcode 12, Swift 5**

for removing separator after last cell, select grouped UITableView style
[You can do that in Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugiGy.png) or setup it in viewDidLoad

```
tableView.style = UITableView.Style.grouped
```

remove empty space before first cell, write this code in viewDidLoad:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: 0.1))
```

for removing empty space before your cells, and you are going to scroll it under the navigation bar or have other difficulties with avoiding empty space, try to constraint your table to controller's super view
[Here double click the top constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcyR0.png) and then choose 'SuperView.Top' [at the constraint settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9Vgj.png)

If you want full width separator or your own width of it, just select Separator Inset as Custom, and configure to your values, or write it in viewDidLoad:

```
tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the last cell index in the `cellForRow` delegate and put the line of code from below:

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(
    0.f,
    40.0f,
    0.f,
    self.view.frame.size.width-40.0f
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is by subclassing `UITableView`:

```
@synthesize hideLastSeparator = _hideLastSeparator;
@synthesize hideLastSeparatorView = _hideLastSeparatorView;
-(void)setHideLastSeparator:(BOOL)hideLastSeparator {
    if (_hideLastSeparator == hideLastSeparator) {
        return;
    }
    _hideLastSeparator = hideLastSeparator;
    if (_hideLastSeparator) {
        _hideLastSeparatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.contentSize.height, self.bounds.size.width, 0.5f)];
        _hideLastSeparatorView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
        _hideLastSeparatorView.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor;
        [self addSubview:_hideLastSeparatorView];
        [self hideSeparator];
    }
    else {
        [_hideLastSeparatorView removeFromSuperview];
        _hideLastSeparatorView = nil;
    }
}
-(void)setContentSize:(CGSize)contentSize {
    [super setContentSize:contentSize];
    if (_hideLastSeparator) {
        [self hideSeparator];
    }
}
-(void)hideSeparator {
    CGRect frame = _hideLastSeparatorView.frame;
    frame.origin.y = self.contentSize.height - frame.size.height;
    _hideLastSeparatorView.frame = frame;
}
```

The .h should only contain property declarations for `hideLastSeparator` and `hideLastSeparatorView`.
When wanting to hide the separator, use the new class and set `myTableView.hideLastSeparator = YES`.
The way this works is by obstructing the last separator by adding a new view over it.

This is somewhat easier to use in my opinion (than using a custom separator, or setting the last separatorInset of the last cell), and avoids some weird animations that the method of setting a `tableFooterView` sometimes causes (e.g. during row insertion/deletion or other table animations).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using custom separators for your `UITableViewCell` the best solution is:

1. Implement in your custom cell function, that hides `separatorView`

```
class YourCell: UITableViewCell {
    // Your implementation goes here...
    // Separator view in cell
    @IBOutlet private weak var separatorView: UIView!

    // This function hides the separator view
    func hideSeparator() {
        separatorView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

2. In `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` calculate if the cell is the last and hides it's separator

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = cell as? YourCell else {
            return
    }
    // Here we're checking if your cell is the last one
    if indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1 {
        // if true -> then hide it
        cell.hideSeparator()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested and is working in Swift 5, iOS 15 and in xCode 13.3.1, Just Paste this code in TableView "cellForRowAt" method just before return cell as it pushes last line out of the frame....Note:-("arrayCartItems" will be your Array which you are returning in "numberOfRowsInSection" and "tblVw" is your Outlet name of UITableView in ViewController) Written in detail so that even Newbies could easily learn:)

```
    if indexPath.row == arrayCartItems.count - 1 {
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: tblVw.bounds.width + 1, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    } else {
        cell.separatorInset = .zero
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The most suitable & easy way would be using this at `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.drawBottonLine = (indexPath.row != sections[0].rows.count - 1)
```

Comment: I don't think `.drawBottonLine` exists?

Answer (score -2):

Expanding on Tonny Xu's answer, I have multiple sections and this seems to work for removing the last cells separator

```
if(indexPath.row == [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1)
{
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 1)];
}
```

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` datasource

Comment: This depends on some a hidden implementation detail - you shouldn't really be doing this; `tableFooterView` exists for the entire table, and not just for the last cell. Overall, hacky solution, and may not always work.