# Height and width interchanging when running from xcode 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode9

I am using latest Xcode 9 to run my project in iPad.

ViewControllers view is not occupying the whole space.When i print the frame I found height and width are interchanging

```
 frame = (0 0; 768 1024)
```

When i run the same in Xcode 8 it's proper

Comment: this is right resolution. where is the problem? also check orientation of ipad, in simulator you have Landscape mode...

Comment: @FahimParkar I am running in landscape mode, so frame should be (0 0; 1024 768)

Comment: [this might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9691450/1066828)

Comment: @FahimParkar Thanks. but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

got to project target, click on general. and show the deployment info, then devices select universal. hope this will be work and please check the attachment image. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need check full screen. Click your app name under TARGETS-> go to general-> see deployment info ->check Requires full screen.
[image]

Comment: that option is already selected, as i said this is happening only when i am running with xcode 9

Comment: Are getting this problem for all iPads OR specific to any iPad

Comment: for all the iPad's